# How to choose region when deploy python web to azure app service?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

When I deploy python web (flask) app to Azure app service, I get the below error

```
message: vs code create web app failed. This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription.
```

My question is how to choose another region in VS code?

Great appreciate any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure subscription comes with limited quotas assigned to each resource. If the deployment has failed with 0 quota instance error, You can increase the quota in specific region by creating a Request increase support request as mentioned [**here**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-resource-quota.md#solution)

You cannot select different region for your Web app once it is deployed, As the Web app instance is deployed in a specific region and cannot be changed. The only option here is to re-deploy a new Python Web app in another region than the one which gives you quota error. Refer below:-

When  I tried deploying Azure Web app via VS Code, By default it picked Central US region and I received the same error code as yours:-

[image]

[image]

***In order to select Region while creating a web app use **`Create New Web app (Advanced)`** option in Vs Code like below:-***

[image]

**Enter the name of Web app:-**

[image]

**Create a new Resource group or select an existing one, I have created a new resource group like below:-**

[image]

**If you are using existing resource group make sure you have created it in different region than Central US** which has quota error:-

[image]

Now, As **I have selected create new resource group, Select the region. Make sure you select another region than Central US. I have selected Australia East** like below:-

[image]

**Enter new App service plan name:-**

[image]

[image]

**Create new application insights resource like below:-**

[image]

***Web app created successfully in Australia East region, Refer below:-***

[image]

**Now deploy your source code to this Web app:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Quickstart: Deploy a Python (Django or Flask) web app to Azure - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli)

Comment: Thanks so much for the very detail answer.Let me try to use "New Web app (Advanced)" to create web app and will update the result later. Thanks again!

Comment: @HarlyChen Glad it was helpful. The option is in Workspace tab below in your Vs code check my third image. Make sure you have Azure extension installed in your vs code with Azure web app extension too. After opening your source code folder in the Workspace tab you will see the option, Select Azure extension > https://i.imgur.com/38GMTMC.png

Comment: The good news is that the creation of the app service was successful. However, the bad news is that the deployment failed after clicking the "Deploy" button due to a timeout.I will depoy it again!